# HTTPConnection.request not respecting timeout?

Tags: python, httpconnection, httplib

I'm trying to use `HTTPConnection` (2.7.8) to make a request and I've set the timeout to 10 with `HTTPConnection(host, timeout=10)`. However, `HTTPConnection.request()` doesn't seem to timeout after 10 seconds. In fact, `HTTPConnection.timeout` doesn't even seem to be read by `HTTPConnection.request()` (it's only read by `HTTPConnection.connect()`. Is my understanding correct? Is `timeout` only applicable to `connect()` and not `request()`? Is there a way to timeout `request()`?

**Update:**

I think I've narrowed the issue down further: if I don't provide the scheme, it won't respect the socket timeout. If the scheme was provided, i.e. the full URL being `http://google.com:22222`, then it'd time out accordingly. I wonder why the presence of the scheme should make a difference. That is, the following doesn't respect the timeout

```
    socket.setdefaulttimeout(3)
    conn = HTTPConnection('google.com:22222')
    conn.timeout = 3
    conn.request('GET', '')
```

whereas, this does:

```
    socket.setdefaulttimeout(3)
    conn = HTTPConnection('http://google.com:22222')
    conn.timeout = 3
    conn.request('GET', '')
```

However, it doesn't happen to all domains.

Thanks

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265720/http-request-timeout. Hope this helps :)

Comment: No, that answer doesn't work for me. It still stuck at `request()`. An example url is google.com:2222

Comment: have you tried to to provide ip address directly (instead of the hostname)? Call `socket.getaddrinfo()`, to get ip address. It seems the same issue as [ftplib.FTP timeout has inconsistent behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28429501/4279): `request()` does several socket operations. Each operation is limited by the timeout. But several operations combined may take longer.

Comment: I think I've narrowed the issue down further: if I don't provide the scheme, it won't respect the socket timeout. If the scheme was provided, i.e. the full URL being `http://google.com:22222`, then it'd time out. I wonder why the presence of the scheme should make a difference.

Comment: It is not clear how you use HTTPConnection. [Create the shortest program that demonstrates the difference](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (set `HTTPConnection.debuglevel=1`)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I've added code snippets now.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I think the suggestion in your first comment explains my problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It takes around ~30 seconds for the following code to fail:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
from httplib import HTTPConnection

conn = HTTPConnection('google.com', 22222, timeout=2)
conn.request('GET', '')
```

If ip is passed to `HTTPConnection` instead of the hostname then the timeout error is raised in 2 seconds as expected:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import socket
from httplib import HTTPConnection

host, port = 'google.com', 22222
ip, port = socket.getaddrinfo(host, port)[0][-1]
conn = HTTPConnection(ip, port, timeout=2)
conn.request('GET', '')
```

The explanation is the same as in [ftplib.FTP timeout has inconsistent behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28429501/4279): the timeout may limit individual socket operations but it says nothing about the duration of the `HTTPConnection()` call itself that may try several ip addresses returned by `getaddrinfo()` and the timeout limits only the individual socket operations. Several operations combined may take longer.

Your `HTTPConnection('http://google.com:22222')` fails sooner because the url is an incorrect argument: it should be either `host` or `host:port`. The absolute `url` is accepted by `request()` method -- though even there it has special meaning -- typically, you just provide the path along such as `'/'`.