# Set timeout for FTP connection in Python with ftplib

Tags: python, ftp, timeout, ftplib

I am triying to set up the timeout of a FTP connection usign:

> class ftplib.FTP([host[, user[, passwd[, acct[, timeout]]]]])
>
> Return a new instance of the FTP class. When host is given, the method call
> connect(host) is made. When user is given, additionally the method
> call login(user, passwd, acct) is made (where passwd and acct default
> to the empty string when not given). The optional timeout parameter
> specifies a timeout in seconds for blocking operations like the
> connection attempt (if is not specified, the global default timeout
> setting will be used).

The problem is that my code to create the connection is as follows:

```
from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP('172.16.52.87')
ftp.login('username', 'password')
```

I found some problems if I use:

```
ftp = FTP('172.16.52.87', 'username', 'password')
```

Then my question is, how can I set up th timeout ?

I have tried let some parameters empty but it does not work:

```
ftp = FTP('172.16.52.87', '', '', '', '100')
```

And login function has only 3 parameters `login(user, passwd, acct)`

Some idea?

Regards

Comment: beware, [`FTP()` may take longer than `timeout` seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28429501/4279)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try:

```
ftp = FTP('172.16.52.87', timeout=100)
ftp.login('user', 'pass)
```

or even

```
ftp = FTP('172.16.52.87', 'user', 'pass', timeout=100)
```

References:

- https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments
- http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/optional_arguments.html